# php preg_replace change so it doesn't remove plus sign +

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Here is the code I have so far:

```
function fix_comma($str) {
  $str = preg_replace('/[^0-9,]|,[0-9]*$/', ',', $str); 
  $str = preg_replace(
      array(
        '/[^\d,]/',    // Matches anything that's not a comma or number.
        '/(?<=,),+/',  // Matches consecutive commas.
        '/^,+/',       // Matches leading commas.
        '/,+$/'        // Matches trailing commas.
      ),
      '',              // Remove all matched substrings.
      $str
    );
  return $str;
}
```

It works nicely to convert text area input into comma delimited sets of number:

103,,,112 - 119 asdf 125 turns into 103,112,119,125

Sometimes users will want a plus sign included with one or more of the numbers:

103 - 112 - 119 - 125+ needs to turn into 103,112,119,125+
or
103, 112, 119, +125 needs to turn into 103,112,119,+125

Can someone fix the function so that if a plus sign is included it is not removed from the final string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case using preg_match_all seems more simple:

```
function fix_comma($str) {
    preg_match_all('~\+?+\d++\+?+~', $str, $matches);
    return implode(',', $matches[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function fix_comma($str) {
  $str = preg_replace('/[^0-9,\+]|,[0-9]*$/', ',', $str); 
  $str = preg_replace(
      array(
        '/[^\d,\+]/',    // Matches anything that's not a comma, + or number.
        '/(?<=,),+/',  // Matches consecutive commas.
        '/^,+/',       // Matches leading commas.
        '/,+$/'        // Matches trailing commas.
      ),
      '',              // Remove all matched substrings.
      $str
    );
  return $str;
}
```

Comment: I see you added to the first preg_replace so that the plus sign makes it through line 2, but the part that removes leading, trailing, and duplicate commas turns right around and removes the plus sign on line 5

Comment: I have added a plus sign there also to pass through. [Demo](http://codepad.org/WCXNxhik)